# All caps string with space in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I got to extract string like  `"THE NEED OF FOLLOWING A RELIGION "` from string.
I extracted individual words like `THE` , `NEED`, `OF`... but I need complete string of capital letter like `"THE NEED OF FOLLOWING A RELIGION"` but not able to do so, please help.

```
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]*/", $html, $out);
```

Thanks

Comment: the regex would need to include spaces too

Comment: but i am unable to make it,, spaces in that. as i dont know. how many spaces will come... and how to make end condition.

Comment: You don't need to worry about number of spaces like you didn't about letters. `/[A-Z ]*/`

Comment: Maybe try this `[A-Z]*(?=\s)|(?<=\s)[A-Z]*`.

Comment: Thanks every one,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very basic modification to the original code to find capitals of more than 1 at a time.

```
$str='This is a string WITH MIXED CASE words and WE ONLY WANT capitals';
preg_match_all("/[A-Z\s]{2,}/", $str, $out);
echo '<pre>',print_r($out,true),'</pre>';
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  WITH MIXED CASE 
            [1] =>  WE ONLY WANT 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex just missed some condition of delimiter, which is

> Words has to be either followed or leaded by a space.

Convert the sentence above to regex we get

```
[A-Z]*(?=\s)|(?<=\s)[A-Z]*
```

The regex above can interpret into either

```
\sWORD
WORD\s
\sWORD\s
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yR3aT4/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the white space to your class like `[A-Z ]`. Now you can get all the strings in capitalized words but also a bench of single spaces.To avoid getting single spaces you use this `([A-Z]+[A-Z ]*[A-Z])` I added the `()` to capture the matched results.
You can check it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/lT4kD9/1).